# Miller-Rabin special case

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

I have question about a homework.

> Why can we be $100\%$ sure after $4$ tests for the special case of $p=13$?

I don't get it. I have a formula that states, that every test increases certainty by $\left(\frac14\right)^k$, where $k$ is the number of tests. So after $4$ tests I get around $99.6\%$ certainty, not $100\%.$

Comment: The Miller-Rabin test for testing if $n$ is prime is probabilistic when choosing the witnesses $x \in \{2,\ldots,n-1\}$ randomly. But if you do the test for $x = 2,3, \ldots \frac{n}{4}$ it becomes deterministic. Actually there are some conjectures that testing for $x = 2,3, \ldots m$ with $m= 2(\log n)^2$  is enough.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants